# Groupby count of values - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping to count specific values from a pandas df. Using below, I'm subsetting `Item` by `Up` and grouping `Num` and `Label` to count the values in `Item`. The values in the output are correct but I want to drop `Label` and include `Up` in the column headers.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Num' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    'Label' : ['A','B','A','B','B','B','A','B','B','A','A','A','B','A','B','A'],   
    'Item' : ['Up','Left','Up','Left','Down','Right','Up','Down','Right','Down','Right','Up','Up','Right','Down','Left'],  
   })

df1 = (df[df['Item'] == 'Up']
      .groupby(['Num','Label'])['Item']
      .count()
      .unstack(fill_value = 0)
      .reset_index()
      )
```

intended output:

```
  Num  A_Up  B_Up
    1     3     0
    2     1     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your approach, you can include the Item in the grouper.

```
out = (df[df['Item'] == 'Up'].groupby(['Num','Label','Item']).size()
       .unstack(['Label','Item'],fill_value=0))
out.columns=out.columns.map('_'.join)

print(out)

     A_Up  B_Up
Num            
1       3     0
2       1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to have all column names. Then use [`df.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and a `list comprehension` to get your desired column names.

```
In [2301]: x = df[df['Item'] == 'Up']
In [2304]: x['c'] = x.groupby(['Num','Label'])['Item'].transform('count')

In [2310]: x = x.pivot_table(index='Num', columns=['Label', 'Item'], aggfunc='first', fill_value=0)
In [2313]: x.columns = [j+'_'+k for i,j,k in x.columns]

In [2314]: x
Out[2314]: 
     A_Up  B_Up
Num            
1       3     0
2       1     1
```